# Adding Tau to Rogue Trader?

Tags: dark-heresy-1e, homebrew, rogue-trader

A friend of mine is thinking of starting up a Rogue Trader game. I've played Dark Heresy before (only 1-2 sessions though), and I've recently seen [this](http://1d4chan.org/wiki/Tau_Dark_Heresy) home brew for dark heresy.

I'm really interested in playing a Tau character (or someone form the tau world, like a Kroot, or Demiurg possibly), and I know that would be possible using those rules in *Dark Heresy*, but would the stats just carry on over to Rogue Trader? Should I start a-fresh with fitting tau into Rogue Trader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is a group working in Tau's on 1d4 chan:

http://1d4chan.org/wiki/Tau_Dark_Heresy

The thing is I don't really feel this stats are accurate. You may want to rethink and and apply the stats you consider appropriate from Tau descriptions.

I had Tau playing in a RT game. In stats I think that I used -10 to WS, +10 to BS, -5 to T, and +5 to Int. To these generic Tau stats, I applied caste modifications, i.e. more Ag and less Str to air caste.

As for classes, the Tau that appeared was from the Earth caste, so I used the techpriest class for her, only avoiding picking the imperial/religious traits. I think every Tau cast would have an equivalent in imperial classes:

Earth: Explorator (tech priest)
Fire: Arch-militant (soldier)
Water: Seneschal (merchant)
Air: Void master (Pilot)
Ethereal: Missionary (Priest)

Comment: I'm aware of the group stating Tau for DH, I've linked it in my question. I am however intrigued by the stats you've given for your game. Could you expand on that please?

Comment: Sorry, that was a long time ago, and I could not find any notes. What I did was to read the Tau descriptions (http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Tau) and make modifiers. DH uses +5 or -5 modifiers, but I used +10, -10 since Tau are different species. That were the base Tau stats modifiers. Then, I read the castes description and applied +5, -5 modifiers to them, since this were inside the same specie. Sorry, I can't recall more that I said. I only needed to create a Tau character, engineer from the earth caste (http://www.4shared.com/office/IGpQbG3z/fios-saal-rala-tomcau.html). Hope that helps.

Comment: @mu That's excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can help you with the Kroot. There's a published supplement called [Into the Storm](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=16087) which has rules for building Kroot and Ork Freebooter characters. Since Kroot tend to use certain Tau weapons, you can probably get some of the stats out of that.

If you want to play a Tau proper, I'd take a look at the Tau stats from Dark Heresy, and double check some of the Talents. Otherwise pretty much everything should carry over (aside from the XP difference between Dark Heresy characters and Rogue Trader characters).